# Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.USP_GetContactDetailsWithBusinessEntity' in worklight

Tags: stored-procedures, ibm-mobilefirst

I have run so many times below code, unable retrieve the data from database. It's connecting to database no problem in it.
Please help me...

sql adapter **.js** code

```
function myLatLang() {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStoredProcedure({
        procedure : "dbo.USP_GetContactDetailsWithBusinessEntity",
        //preparedStatement : myLatLangStatement,
        parameters : []
    });
}
```

This is **JSON** output

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: Failed to retrieve data with procedure : dbo.USP_GetContactDetailsWithBusinessEntity"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Comment: Where is the procedure... Add the code from the adapter's impl.js file.

Comment: above code from that .js file only...

Comment: Where is the implementation of dbo.USP_GetContactDetailsWithBusinessEntity.

Comment: now see above code...

Comment: is it enough or anything need to add?

Answer (score 1):

i changed the procedure from

**procedure : "[USP_GetContactDetailsWithBusinessEntity]"**

like this

**procedure : "[go2needs_online].[dbo].[USP_GetContactDetailsWithBusinessEntity]"**